# TypeError: document.on is not a function

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar

ROR newbie here.  I am attempting to use [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/usage/) with ROR 3.2.11 on Ubuntu 12.  I've downloaded a [working example](https://github.com/bokmann/rails3_fullcalendar) and verified the calender does display in the sample app.  However, it does not in my app.  I installed Firebug to see if there are any JavaScript errors and there are 2:

```
TypeError: document.on is not a function   <location rails.js:128>
TypeError: $(...).fullCalendar is not a function   <location calendar.js:48>
```

I don't understand what the errors mean.  Keep in mind I did not write these JavaScripts, so I don't understand them.

Hoping someone who has come across this error and solution can help.

Comment: It probably means jQuery is not included correctly or you are not using it correctly. It's hard to tell anything without seeing your code.

Comment: Replace `document.on()` with `$(document).on()`.

Comment: @Bergi what about the other error? Do you have an idea what the asker could have done wrong?

Comment: @JanDvorak: Not sure, there are multiple possible causes :-) Sounds like the calendar plugin is not (or not correctly) included

Comment: @Bergi then why does the examp... oh, it's a different page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$(document).on()` is a jQuery construct (see http://api.jquery.com/on/).  `$(...).fullCalendar()` also smells like a jQuery plugin.  Reference jQuery earlier in your page (see https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery) and it should light up.

Comment: Wow, you guys and gals are awesome!  Looks like the asset pipeline that comes in ROR 3.1 has a little caution to it.  It loads the javascript alphabetically (it's because of that dang song ... ABCDEFG...).  I added all the jquery*.js file requires specifically before the asset pipeline requires:

Comment: //= require jquery
//= require jquery-1.8.1.min
//= require jquery.rest
//= require jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require vendor
//= require_tree .

I just removed rails.js as I only copied it in because it was used in the working example.

Answer (score 2):

Check your jquery version, it should be at least 1.7 for $(document).on() to work.